# Advanced string manipulation in SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was asked to create FUNCTION that will join strings from two columns into one - to be used in SELECT statement

Column 1: Message template with %1, %2, %3 as a placeholders for values. Example: `User %2 logged in to %3 at %1`

Column 2: Invalid XML (without single root), with values: Example: `<Param>11:00:00</Param><Param>admin</Param><Param>computer 1</Param>`

Expected result: `User admin logged in to computer 1 at 11:00:00`
There is no limit for number of parameters, their order nor repetition. I assume that xml-like characters (`<,>`) are escaped inside the parameters.

I reached this stage when writing pure SQL:

```
DECLARE @params xml = '<Param>999</Param><Param>22</Param>'
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar(max) = '%1 :: %2'
DECLARE @paramIndex int = 0

set rowcount 0
select NULL tempKey, s.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as param into #temp_table3 from @params.nodes('/Param') as s(c)

set rowcount 1
update #temp_table3 set tempKey = 1


while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    DECLARE @currParam nvarchar(max)
    set @paramIndex = @paramIndex+1

    set rowcount 0

    select @currParam = param from #temp_table3 where tempKey = 1
    set @pattern = replace(@pattern, '%'+CAST(@paramIndex as varchar), @currParam)

    delete #temp_table3 where tempKey = 1
    set rowcount 1
    update #temp_table3 set tempKey = 1
end

set rowcount 0

select @pattern
```

It was working fine as a standalone SQL but then I tried to move it to the function...
I replaced temp table with table variable, but I stuck with replacement for `set rowcount 1` ("Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET ROW COUNT' within a function.")- or iterating over @tempTable in general.

Any suggestions how can I fix it?

For your convenience, function at this moment (simplified):

```
CREATE FUNCTION sch1.getEvent (@eventString nvarchar(max), @eventParams xml)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS 

BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @eventDescription nvarchar(max) 
    SET @eventDescription=@eventString
    
    DECLARE @idx INT
    SET @idx = 0

    DECLARE @tempTable table (
        tempKey int, 
        param nvarchar(max)
    )

    set rowcount 0
    insert @tempTable
    select 
        NULL, 
        s.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    from @eventParams.nodes('/Param') as s(c)

    set rowcount 1
    update @tempTable set tempKey = 1

    while @@rowcount > 0
    begin
        DECLARE @currParam nvarchar(max)
        set @idx = @idx+1

        set rowcount 0

        select @currParam = param from @tempTable where tempKey = 1
        set @eventDescription = replace(@eventDescription, '%'+CAST(@idx as varchar), @currParam)

        delete @tempTable where tempKey = 1
        set rowcount 1
        update @tempTable set tempKey = 1
    end

    set rowcount 0


    RETURN @eventDescription
END
```

Comment: The blunt answer would be, this isn't a task for SQL Server. Though you *could*  (ab)use [`FORMATMESSAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): `SELECT FORMATMESSAGE(N'This is my string: %s',N'My string')`. `SELECT FORMATMESSAGE(N'This is my %s, it has a int value, %i.', N'Message', 17);`

Comment: The default answer to any question asking for advanced string manipulation in SQL is `Don't do that`. SQL is a query language, not a text manipulation language. It's notoriously weak in text manipulation and T-SQL in particular has none of the custom extensions found in other databases. Using SQL as a text template engine may be interesting as code golf but completely impractical for any use

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why not generate the string in any client language? Once you load the results, generating the lines would need only a few lines. In C# for example, `events.Select(evt=>$"User {evt.User} logged in to {evt.Machine} at {evt.Time}")`. Using eg Dapper, the query itself could be one line: `var events=con.Query<Event>("select * from Events where date>@lastDate",new {lastDate});`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - we are not living in the perfect world. If customer says "I want it no matter what" you stop talking about performance drop, you do what you are paid for.

Comment: @user2706534 on the contrary, they pay you to tell them what the correct solution is. Otherwise you're wasting their money. Customers never specify how you should do something, they ask for solutions to their business problems. It's developers that come up with hacky code because they misunderstood the requirement. Quite often this happens in consulting companies that promised a bad solution and are afraid to tell the customer they need to change it. That's detrimental to both the consulting company's and its employees' prospects

Comment: @user2706534 right now, Larnu's solution is far better than this sea of code - easier to write and maintain, faster to execute. Even simple string concatenation is better. Or nested `REPLACE` calls to replace placeholders with values, eg `REPLACE(REPLACE(template,'%1',field1),'%2',field2)`. If you really want a "complex" solution you can write a SQLCLR function that performs a `String.Format` with the row values. In SQL Server 2017 and later you can use a Python script and a real template module right inside SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It was like rubber duck session...
I've replaced table variable with cursor and voila

```
    DECLARE paramsCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    select
        s.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    from @eventParams.nodes('/Param') as s(c)
```

Comment: `FAST_FORWARD` implies `FORWARD_ONLY` and `READ_ONLY`. And `s.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')` is slightly faster